# Remove element from 2d numpy array without loosing structure

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I would like to remove a specific character from a 2d numpy array. For example:

```
myarr = np.array([[2,"?",5,2,3,6,8],[6,7,8,9,"?"]])
```

How can I delete "?" without loosing the structure of the array? My result should look like this:

```
 [[2,5,2,3,6,8]
  [6,7,8,9]]
```

(I am using Python 3.4.2 and numpy 1.9 on a Win7 machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myarr = np.array([[2,"?",5,2,3,6,8],[6,7,8,9,"?"]])` produces

```
array([[2, '?', 5, 2, 3, 6, 8], [6, 7, 8, 9, '?']], dtype=object)
```

That is an array of 2 items of type `object`.  There isn't an 'structure'.  This is basically the same as a list of lists

```
mylist = [[2, '?', 5, 2, 3, 6, 8], [6, 7, 8, 9, '?']]
```

A simple way of removing the '?' is:

```
for l in mylist:
    l.remove('?')
```

But this raises a ValueError if there isn't any '?' in the sublist, and does not remove all if there is more than one.  Both of those faults could be fixed by writing a small function that counts the number of occurrences, and removes the right number.  Can you handle that function?

So the problem comes down to removing selected elements from a list of lists (or array of lists).

---

the 'remove all' function is simpler than I thought:

```
 def remove_all(a,x):
     while x in a:
         a.remove(x)
 for a in myarr:
     a.remove_all('?')
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I have just started with numpy and was not aware of the list/array confusion in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy arrays must be "rectangular", that is, all rows/columns must have the same length. Your example looks like you need a "jagged array", which numpy doesn't support.

If this is just a case of poorly-picked example, you can remove the ? elements by selecting all non-? elements:

```
result = myarr[myarr!='?']
```

Comment: If numpy is not supporting this, what does "myarr" in the above example represent and why do I get not error message when constructing an object with an np.array() command which is not supported by np?